# Array index out of bounds when making it check the list in reverse

Tags: c#, indexoutofboundsexception

so after my previous issue got fixed i went to add some more code and i'v been trying looking on here and other places i cant find anything that explains my issue so is there a way to make this code

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    worldX = 0;
    worldY = 0;
    while (worldY != WorldHeight) { 
         while (worldX != WorldWidth) {
             if (worldY > 0) {
                 if (worldX > 0) {
                    if (world[worldX-1, worldY-1] == 1 && genran.Next(genran.Next(genran.Next(-7,-1),genran.Next(0,2)),genran.Next(genran.Next(5,8),genran.Next(9,16))) > 6) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1;}
                    } if ((worldX + 1) < WorldWidth) {
                    if (world[worldX+1, worldY-1] == 1 && genran.Next(genran.Next(genran.Next(-7,-1),genran.Next(0,2)),genran.Next(genran.Next(5,8),genran.Next(9,16))) > 6) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1;}
                 }
             }
             worldX++;
         }
         worldX = 0;
         worldY++;
     }
 }
```

into something like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    worldX = WorldWidth;
    worldY = WorldHeight;
    while (worldY >= 0) { 
         while (worldX >= 0) {
             if (worldY > 0) {
                 if (worldX > 0) {
                    if (world[worldX-1, worldY-1] == 1 && genran.Next(genran.Next(genran.Next(-7,-1),genran.Next(0,2)),genran.Next(genran.Next(5,8),genran.Next(9,16))) > 6) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1;}
                    } if ((worldX - 1) > 0) {
                    if (world[worldX+1, worldY-1] == 1 && genran.Next(genran.Next(genran.Next(-7,-1),genran.Next(0,2)),genran.Next(genran.Next(5,8),genran.Next(9,16))) > 6) { world[worldX, worldY] = 1;}
                 }
             }
             worldX--;
         }
         worldX = WorldWidth;
         worldY--;
     }
 }
```

so instead of starting at the top left i want to start at the bottom right an go backwards from there

PS. I'm still new to some of this.

Comment: You can't find anything that explains your issue? Have you checked each of the values with the debugger as you go through?

Comment: What the hack does this code do: `genran.Next(genran.Next(genran.Next(-7,-1),genran.Next(0,2)),genran.Next(genran.Next(5,8),genran.Next(9,16)))` and why so many magic numbers? I do not really want to know.

Comment: @FrankFajardo its just a very, idk Convoluted way of making it 'more random'

Comment: Maybe worthwhile to refactor that out since they are repetitive, and may make your code easier to read/understand. Also, try writing to console the value of variables that control the loop so you can see where it is going.

Comment: Exception probably occurs at line `world[worldX+1, worldY-1]` when `worldX+1` equals `WorldWidth`. Your former program actually correctly check this condition with `if ((worldX + 1) < WorldWidth)`, but in the second program you replaced this condition with `if ((worldX - 1) > 0)`, which doesn't make sense and does not prevent accessing array out-of-bounds.